# How to limit storage size of hornet node?

Tags: hornet

How in the config to I limit the storage to 10GB or so.

Here is my config section on snapshots

```
"snapshots": {
"loadType": "local",
"local": {
  "intervalSynced": 50,
  "intervalUnsynced": 1000,
  "path": "snapshots/mainnet/export.bin",
  "downloadURLs": [
    "https://ls.manapotion.io/export.bin",
    "https://x-vps.com/export.bin",
    "https://dbfiles.iota.org/mainnet/hornet/latest-export.bin"
  ]
},
"global": {
  "path": "snapshotMainnet.txt",
  "spentAddressesPaths": [
    "previousEpochsSpentAddresses1.txt",
    "previousEpochsSpentAddresses2.txt",
    "previousEpochsSpentAddresses3.txt"
  ],
  "index": 1050000
},
"pruning": {
  "enabled": true,
  "delay": 60480
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as of today 5000 snapshots are around 20gb.
For your setup I would propose 2000, or less to have some space left.